# d3-ng2-service error "property Links does not exists of type force()"

Tags: angular, d3.js

I have just started using Angularjs 2 and d3-ng2-service and I am trying to get a network chart working.

I use example

https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2675ff61ea5e063ede2b5d63c08020c7

and transitioning it to d3-ng2-service.

I am getting the following error

"property Links does not exists of type force()"

With the following code

```
simulation.force("link")
    .links(links);
```

Full code listed below

```
import { Component, ElementRef, NgZone, OnDestroy, OnInit } from     '@angular/core';

import { links, nodes} from './networkData.component';

import {
  D3Service,
  D3,
  Axis,
  ScaleLinear,
  ScaleOrdinal,
  Selection,
  Simulation,
  Transition
} from 'd3-ng2-service';


@Component({
  selector: 'network1',
  template: '<svg width="100%" height="100%"></svg>',
  styleUrls: ['./network.component.css']
})
export class Network1Component implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private d3: D3;
  private parentNativeElement: any;
  private d3Svg: Selection<SVGSVGElement, any, null, undefined>;


  constructor(element: ElementRef, private ngZone: NgZone, d3Service: D3Service)    {
    this.d3 = d3Service.getD3();
    this.parentNativeElement = element.nativeElement;
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.d3Svg.empty && !this.d3Svg.empty()) {
      this.d3Svg.selectAll('*').remove();
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
        let self = this;
    let d3 = this.d3;
    let width: number;
    let height: number;
    let d3ParentElement: Selection<HTMLElement, any, null, undefined>;
    let d3Svg: Selection<SVGSVGElement, any, null, undefined>;




    if (this.parentNativeElement !== null) {

      d3ParentElement = d3.select(this.parentNativeElement);
      d3Svg = this.d3Svg = d3ParentElement.select<SVGSVGElement>('svg');

      width = +d3Svg.attr('width');
      height = +d3Svg.attr('height');

      var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

      var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d[0].id; }))
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
        .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

      var link = d3Svg.append<SVGGElement>('g')
        .attr("class", "links")
        .selectAll("line")
        .data(links)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

      var node = d3Svg.append<SVGGElement>('g')
        .attr("class", "nodes")
        .selectAll("circle")
        .data(nodes)
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.id); });


      node.append("title")
        .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

      simulation
        .nodes(nodes)
        .on("tick", ticked);

        simulation.force("link")
        .links(links);


    }

    function ticked() {
      link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target; });

      node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.id; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.id; });
    }

    function dragstarted(d) {
      if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
      d.fx = d.x;
      d.fy = d.y;
    }

    function dragged(d) {
      d.fx = d3.event.x;
      d.fy = d3.event.y;
    }

    function dragended(d) {
      if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
      d.fx = null;
      d.fy = null;
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

In porting the bl.ock to TypeScript, there are a couple of tweaks required to ensure the data types of nodes and links and the varying force types are handled correctly.

`forceSimulation` accepts two generics when invoking it. Let us assume, your nodes are of type `YourNodeType` which extends the `SimulationNodeDatum` and links are of type `YourLinkType` which extends `SimulationLinkDatum<YourNodeType>`.`SimulationNodeDatum` and `SimulationLinkDatum` are interfaces defined in the **d3-force** definitions.

(see [d3-force definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/d3-force/index.d.ts#L25)).

With that said, you should define `let simulation = d3.forceSimulation<YourNodeType, YourLinkType>()` This way, node and for your case importantly link types are enforced throughout the simulation.

Now to the core of the error you experience, in order to retrieve a force with properties other than the minimal `Force` interface,it is necessary to cast the force to the ex ante known type. In your case the link force has a pre-defined interface in the definitions.

So `simulation.force<ForceLink<YourNodeType, YourLinkType>>('link')`, will return a link force with defined `links()` method.

A couple of housekeeping comments, since you are using **d3-ng2-service**, the interfaces `SimulationNodeDatum`, `SimulationLinkDatum` and `ForceLink` can be imported directly from `d3-ng2-service` into the file containing your angular component.

If you are using `strictNullChecks`, you may want to `simulation.force<ForceLink<YourNodeType, YourLinkType>>('link')!.links()`, where `!` addresses the case where the returned force might be `undefined` in general. Not the case for you, obviously.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Tom's answer pointed me in the right direction and I managed to get this working - thanks Tom. For anyone else working through this, in my case I also had to add `.links(links)` to `simulation.force()` so:

```
simulation.force("link").links(links);
```

becomes:

```
simulation.force<ForceLink<any, any>>('link').links(links);
```

I'd add this as a comment, but my rep isn't high enough.